# Displaying selected OPTION in HTML dropdown menu on refresh, not value - possible?

Tags: html, drop-down-menu

My drop down menu has genres that it displays, but numbers as the values, eg

```
<option value=240>Alternative Rock</option>
```

My POST data deals with just the value - that's all I need for my database, and it works fine.

However, I'd like to display the selected option after submission, which I would normally do like this if the option and value are the same...

```
if ( isset($_POST['genre']) && $_POST['genre'] != "" && $_POST['genre'] != "undefined" ) echo stripslashes(htmlentities($_POST['genre'])); else echo 'All';
```

But since they are not the same, after submission the above example now displays "240" as it's selection, not "Alternative Rock".

How do I get it to remember the display option, not just the value, while still getting the numerical value that my database queries need?

Thanks for taking a look.

Answer (score 0):

The POST is not going to include the disable value by default. There are a couple options... You can store all the options on the server side while the original page is being created (for example, in a session variable), and then look up the display value when the POST comes in. Or you can use JavaScript to set a hidden form element with the display value, when the user submits the form.

Comment: Thanks Brady. The problem I'm encountering after refresh, if I display the option's name in the drop down, is it sends the name through as the value on the next submit instead of the value (number). Is there a way to tell the drop down on refresh "select the option where value=x"? Cheers.

Comment: My other option is to go back to what I had ie the value and the option are both the actual tag name, and query the db first to get the IDs to build the actual search query, rather than build it with the IDs from the drop down. Either way, I have to query for the tag IDs.

Comment: To you first comment, you're saying the HTML is different after you refresh? It sounds like the second time the option value attribute is missing. If there is no value attribute, the form will assume the display value is the value to send.